# C# ASP.NET, Azure hybrid sql connection cannot connect to Database on Web forms application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, azure

Our company want to deploy a web forms application, but still run our database locally. Azure hybrid connection lets you do this. I have created a new project and followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/) from Microsoft azure.

The app works when debugging and I can add new users to the database and log in. The app runs when deployed, but when I want to login or add a new user to the Membership database it gives me: "**Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**".

The connectionstring in web.config:

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=MyServerName\\MAILREGLOCAL,1433; Database=MembershipDB; User ID=myID; Password=myPassword"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
[OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +347
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +426
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +375
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +86
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +151
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +138
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +145
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +473
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +359
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +160
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn(SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout) +127
   TestDeployForms.Account.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) +147
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext() +5911
```

Comment: did you already check out this issue mentioned ? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/05/17/hybrid-connection-error-with-sql-server-system-overflowexception-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow/

Answer (score 1):

Wow, did not expect that - thanks Aravind for pointing me to [this site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/05/17/hybrid-connection-error-with-sql-server-system-overflowexception-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow/).

What fixed the problem was following these instructions from MSDN:

**

```
The instructions need to be followed on hosts running the Hybrid Connection Manager.  The instructions for directly editing the registry are:
To add this schannel registry entry registry entry, follow these steps:
1.Click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.
2.Locate and then click the following subkey in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
3.On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
4.Type SendExtraRecord for the name of the DWORD value, and then press Enter.
5.Right-click SendExtraRecord, and then click Modify.
6.In the Value data box, type 2 to disable the split record in schannel, and then click OK.
7.Exit Registry Editor.
8. Restart the Azure Hybrid Connection Manager Service or reboot the machine the Azure Hybrid Connection Manager Service is installed on (see the security update to determine which is required, or reboot the machine to be safe)
Make sure that if you copy/paste the key name you don’t accidentally put a space in at the end.
Make sure you name the DWORD “SendExtraRecord”
Make sure the DWORD was set to 2.
```

**

Comment: This is not solving it for me. Has a lot of people had success with this workaround?